# How to simplify this expression and try to make $m=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to simplify this expression

$\cosh(2n s) \cos( 2 m s) = 2 \cosh (w/2) \cos(m s) \sinh(n s)$

I tried to find  $m=?$

I try this solution $\frac{\cos( 2 m s)}{\cos(m s)}=2 \cosh (w/2)\frac{\sinh(n s)}{\cosh(2n s)}$
What should I do after that?

Answer (score 0):

HINT
you could use $\cos(2ms)=2\cos^2(ms)-1$ and then form and solve a quadratic in $\cos(ms)$